# Why is this constant from a Dictionary not unwrapped?

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

I'm using some base swift functionality, the fact that you can unwrapped Optional values with a `if`. I am working on swift 4 and Xcode 10.3

```
let xyz: String? = nil

if let unwrappedValue = xyz {
    print("This is unwrapped")
} else {
    print("This is not unwrapped") // Program goes there
}
```

I have made a dictionary with an Optional value as an element, and when I try to unwrap it, it doesn't unwrap the variable, but keeps the Optional value.

```
var referenceDatesIdentifiers: [String: Date?] =
    ["ReferenceDateIdentifier": nil]

if let referenceDate = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"] {
   referenceDateLabel.text = otherDateFormater.string(from: referenceDate!) // ReferenceDate is Optional and not unwrapped
}
```

Why isn't `referenceDate` unwrapped ?

I tried to export the elem of the Dictionary in a constant, but same problem, it's not unwrapped

```
let refDateOpt = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"]
if let referenceDate = refDateOpt {
    referenceDateLabel.text = otherDateFormater.string(from: referenceDate!) // Reference date is also Optional and not unwrapped
}
```

What is happening ?

Comment: You should never create dictionaries that contain optional values because that way accessing a value you get a double optional `Date??`. You have to unwrap *twice*. There is no good reason to use `[String: Date?]` instead of `[String: Date]`.

Comment: As said by Sulthan, it's Double optional, because: who said that `referenceDatesIdentifiers[randomKeyWhichDoesntExist]` should return non-nil value each time? So this one is optional. And since you said that the value inside might also be optional...

Comment: An optional dictionary value makes no sense. In terms of dictionary semantics a `nil` *value* indicates that the key is missing.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. I'm gonna add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that it doesn't makes any sense to create a dictionary with a nil value. So instead of checking if the key exists before adding a value, I just add the value and check the value with a `if let`

In the end, this was the answer

```
    var referenceDatesIdentifiers: [String : Date] = [:]
    if let referenceDate = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"] {
       referenceDateLabel.text = otherDateFormater.string(from: referenceDate)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should required again optionally unwrap date with type casting will fix your issue. Update code as follow:

```
if let referenceDate = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"] as? Date {
    print(referenceDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below way. It will work perfectly.Update code as follow:

```
var referenceDatesIdentifiers: [String: Date?] =
["ReferenceDateIdentifier": nil]
if let refDateOpt = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"] as? Date {
print(refDateOpt)
```

}

or

```
if let refDateOpt = referenceDatesIdentifiers["ReferenceDateIdentifier"]{
if let referenceDate = refDateOpt {
    print(referenceDate)
}
```

}